# C# dll not found at compile time

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, compilation

I'm writing an application in .Net 3.5.

I have 3 projects in the solution so far. When adding the references to the other projects from my main project, the intellisense manages to find the classes from the other project's dlls but at compile time it seems to be "loosing" the reference.

This might be because I initially created the project with target framework .Net 4.0. However since I needed to use the ASP.NET web services I had to downgrade to 3.5.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a compiler error while compiling? If so, please post it. Or  do you get a runtime error?
Have you downgraded all of your projects to .NET 3.5?

Comment: yes I get a compiler error. The error states the "MyClass cannot be found" i.e. the same error you get when you forget to add the reference to your project

Answer (score 0):

The referrenced projects must be Copy Local : True
Referrence -> Properites ->Copy Local : True

Comment: Copy local is required when you are deploying an assembly where the dll is not already available. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. However I'm unsure where to find the Copy Local option

Comment: Just open your project's "References" section, click on the said reference and in the properties grid, set the "Copy Local" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Batch clean all projects in your solution, make sure all the projects in your dependency graph target the .NET 3.5 framework. Check the reference's HintPath in your .csproj file (open with text editor) for references to external DLLs and make sure they're all <=3.5.

> However since I needed to use the ASP.NET web services I had to downgrade to 3.5.

There are also several different web service projects in .NET 4. I don't quite understand this move.

Comment: If I set the target framework to .Net 4.0 visual studio will hide away asp.net web services. Instead only WCF services are visible.

BTW all my projects where cleaned and their target framework set to 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You have project references, intellisense *sees* your referenced classes but when compiling, the compiler seems not to find the referenced assemblies.

I see two possible reasons for this behaviour:

1. Your main project references a lower version of the .NET framework than your library projects (this is the most likely cause).
2. Your library projects won't get built at all / or in the wrong order (check the settings in the configuration manager. Open it with a right click on your solution in the solition explorer).

Comment: Point 1.: No, All projects' .Net Framework is 3.5
Point 2.: Tried compiling them 1 at a time in the correct sequence, problem still there :/

Comment: Do you compile all the projects with the same configuration / platform settings?